# page method question

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building an asp.net page that uses a page method call from jquery. This is a simple test page but I can't get it to work and I can't see why.

I added a script manager to the aspx. Here's the javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function CallGetLoaded() {

        var ConfirmLoad = "test string";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Pages/TestPage.aspx/GetLoaded",
            data: ConfirmLoad,
            contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "text",
            success: successLoadLeads,
            error: errorLoadLeads
        });

    };

    function successLoadLeads(thereturn) { alert((thereturn)); };
    function errorLoadLeads() { alert("problem getting return"); };

</script>
```

And here's the full code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class Pages_TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetLoaded(string ConfirmLoad)
    {

        string ResultString = "got test";

        return ResultString;
    }
}
```

Instead of getting back a simple string in the alert popup, I'm sometimes getting back the HTML of the whole page and sometimes the error function; not sure why it varies.
What am I missing?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What does the markup for your testpage look like?

Comment: It's empty, it's got a div that contains a text that's clicked to trigger the function.  $(function () {
  $('#testclick').click(function () { CallGetLoaded(); });
 });

Comment: I'll be a bit more specific: the class name (Pages_TestPage) in the code behind looks very suspicious given the actual path of /pages/testpage.aspx.  Almost looks like you renamed a page.  My question is what is the class reference (inherits="...") in your markup?  I'm wondering if your page is using the correct code behind code file.

Comment: It says: Inherits="Pages_TestPage"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some small changes to your code.

1. Changed your `contentType`, `data` and `dataType` of your `$.ajax` request
2. Changed your `onsuccess` handler to check for `.hasOwnProperty("d")`
3. Changed your `onerror` handler so that you may see what the actual error is.

I strongly believe that you had a parse error since you used `text` for parsing and retrieving.

Here is a sample done from your code that works.

The MarkUp

```
<asp:Button ID="testclick" runat="server" Text="Click Me"/>
```

The Scripts

```
$(function () {
    $('#testclick').click(function (e) {
        CallGetLoaded();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function CallGetLoaded() {

    var ConfirmLoad = "test string";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "TestPage.aspx/Getloaded",
        data: "{'ConfirmLoad':'" + ConfirmLoad + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var data = msg.hasOwnProperty("d") ? msg.d : msg;
            OnSucessCallBack(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    });

};

function OnSucessCallBack(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

The Code-Behind

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetLoaded(string ConfirmLoad)
{
    string ResultString = "got test";
    return ResultString;
}
```

P.S: As FiveTools have correctly pointed out,

<strike>`url:"../Pages/TestPage.aspx/Getloaded"`</strike> is unnecessary. `url:"TestPage.aspx/Getloaded"` will do.

Comment: ok, thank you; your demo code for page method works and I'm sure it'll google pretty well for others too. Thanks!

Comment: @frenchie: there is something called encosia.com just visit that. i am just sharing that wisdom :)

Answer (score 0):

try url: "TestPage.aspx/GetLoaded",

Comment: No, I keep getting the error function's message. The URL is correct. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: yes, the alert works; it's just showing "problem getting return" instead of "got test".

Comment: Note: when I put a breakpoint in the code behind, it doesn't trigger.

Comment: Yes, if I add something like alert("WBEWBWEGBER"); I get this message, I know the javascript is working because it's called by a jquery event that's triggered when the user clicks on a div. Jquery is loaded.

Comment: Can you paste the complete aspx source?  I don't see  url: "../Pages/TestPage.aspx/GetLoaded" as being correct.  When I've done this I only needed the page "ThePageWithTheAjaxCall.aspx/Thewebmethodinthecodebehind".  Have you tried this (give me affirmation it doesn't work when it's changed as I suggested).